# Java swing application and php web application synchronisation

Tags: java, php, swing, triggers, synchronization

i have two applications web(PHP) and desktop(swing) that do exactly the same thing but use different database, i want to synchronize both application, i thought about using triggers and i think is the easiest way to do so, if you have other ideas/solutions let me know about them.

Comment: why not to use the same database for both apps?

Comment: it's quite not possible, both database are totally different, otherwise i have to re code the whole source script to get it suitable to the new db which is quite complicating..